# SQL to handle table updates in a "dynamically typed" fashion

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-3.x

I'm playing around with Python 3's `sqlite3` module, and acquainting myself with SQL in the process.

I've written a toy program to hash a salted password and store it, the associated username, and the salt into a database. I thought it would be intuitive to create a function of the signature:

```
def store(table, data, database=':memory:')
```

Callable as, for example, `store('logins', {'username': 'bob', 'salt': 'foo', 'salted_hash' : 'bar'})`, and be able to individually add into `logins`, into new a row, the value `bob` for `username`, `foo` for `salt`, et caetera.

Unfortunately I'm swamped with what SQL to code. I'm trying to do this in a "dynamically typed" fashion, in that I won't be punished for storing the wrong types, or be able to add new columns at will, for example.

I want the function to, sanitizing all input:

- Check if the table exists, and create it if it doesn't, with the passed keys from the dictionary as the columns;
- If the table already exists, check if a table has the specified columns (the keys to the passed dictionary), and add them if it doesn't (is this even possible with SQL?);
- Add the individual values from my dictionary to the appropriate columns in the dictionary.

I can use `INSERT` for the latter, but it seems very rigid. What happens if the columns don't exist, for example? How could we then add them?

I don't mind whether the code is tailored to Python 3's `sqlite3`, or just the SQL as an outline; as long as I can work it and use it to some extent (and learn from it) I'm very grateful.

(On a different note, I'm wondering what other approaches I could use instead of a SQL'd relational database; I've used Amazon's SimpleDB before and have considered using that for this purpose as it was *very* "dynamically typed", but I want to know what SQL code I'd have to use for this purpose.)

Comment: Have you considered using a full-blown ORM? SQLAlchemy (http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) is pretty snazzy

Comment: An rdbms like sqlite isn't the right choice if you want a total schemaless/dynamic experience.

Answer (score 2):

1. SQLite3 is dynamically typed, so no problem there.
2. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <name> ...` See [here.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)
3. You can see if the columns you need already exist in the table by using `sqlite_master` documented in [this FAQ.](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7) You'll need to parse the `sql` column, but since it's exactly what your program provided to create the table, you should know the syntax.
4. If the column does not exist, you can `ALTER TABLE <nam>? ADD COLUMN ...` See [here.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)